# How to get text embedding from spacy's pipeline in a vectorised way?

Tags: python, spacy

I have the following code to get a list of text embeddings from spacy:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_use_md")
texts = ["This Empire Strikes Back", "The Hello World Project", "Mario Brothers"]
docs = list(nlp.pipe(texts))
lst_emb = []
for doc in docs:
    lst_emb.append(doc.vector)   # text embedding
print(texts[0], lst_emb[0][:5])   # show first 5 'coz embedding is (512,)
```

I suspect the for-loop is not the most efficient way of doing this. How should I vectorise it? Is there a way to do something like `lst_emb = nlp.pipe(texts)->get_list_of_embeddings`

Comment: There is no need for `list` in `docs = list(nlp.pipe(texts))`. `docs = nlp.pipe(texts)` suffice.